# How to exit current HTML tag in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, windows-7, sublimetext3

I recently started using Sublime Text 3 + Emmet to code in HTML. I am currently having trouble exiting a tag and have to use the arrows keys, which I do not like.

Example : I want to use a strong tag inside a p. So I type

```
<p>This is an str
```

then press Tab, which causes Emmet to expand the strong tag. What I have under my eyes is now

```
<p>This is an <strong></strong>
```

and my cursor is inside the strong tag. I then type my word

```
<p>This is an <strong>important</strong>
```

Now how do I cause my cursor to go after the end strong tag to continue typing outside the strong tag and finish my paragraph?

```
<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> word but now I want to move on</p>
```

I hope this is clear enough (English is not my mother tongue, blah blah blah).

What I do know is press Ctrl + Right twice (sometimes more) but this is not very fast and requires my to move my right hand and to look what I'm doing. I could do an Autohotkey thingy but I'm not very good at it and it would only work in certain particular cases. Does any of you know if there is a shortcut or a package to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Alexandre

EDIT : I was afraid my message wouldn't be clear enough. I want to go from

```
<p><strong>This is XXX very important</strong></p>
```

to

```
<p><strong>This is very important</strong>XXX</p>
```

where XXX is my text cursor/caret.

Comment: Please specify your OS.

Comment: You can press End to get to the end of the line, and then arrow-key your way back to where you want?

Comment: @Lee I can, but that's really slown, not automatic (i.e. I have to watch what my text cursor does) and it makes me move my right hand.

Comment: Then your answer is no, and don't be so lazy. You're a web develop... You're supposed to develop.

Comment: @Lee What's wrong with you? I'm just asking how to do something quicker while putting less strain on my hands. Your answer like telling a butcher to not use electric tools because after all, he's a butcher and he's supposed to butcher. If you don't know, just skip the question, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no lines under you can press down arrow.

Even if there are lines below you can press down arrow, left arrow.

Not sure if this trick works on Sublime.

TIP: You can always press Right-CTRL with your thumb.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to work on ST3. Also, I believe this goes at the end of the line, not at the end of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best solution, but you can create your own snippet with an additional tabstop.

Save this as `str.sublime-snippet` somewhere in your user directory:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<strong>$1</strong>$0
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>str</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js, source.javascript, text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Now you can write `str`, hit tab, write your words, and hit tab again to move the cursor behind the closing tag.

The problem is, you probably don't want to do this for every tag. I use an arbitrary tag snippet for that purpose:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<$1>$2</$1>$0
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>t</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js, source.javascript, text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, your second snippet is pretty cool ! I added a line in my ahk autocorrect script that goes like this : "::str::strong" which makes str expand to strong when tab is pressed, even inside a tag. The other solution I found was to map ctrl+space to get out of the tag, using ahk as well : "^Space::send ^{Right 2}"